# How to send button value with form

Tags: html, ajax

I have a form and ajax.

I can't send with `$(form).serialize();`

How do I send the button value with the form?

html:

```
<form action="" id="ogrenci_arama_formu">
            <input type="text" id="eposta" name="eposta">
            <button id="ogrenci_ara" name="ogrenci_ara" value="true" class="btn btn-info">Öğrenciyi Ara</button>
            <!--<input id="ogrenci_ara" type="hidden" name="ogrenci_ara" value="true">-->
        </form>
```

ajax:

```
$("#ogrenci_arama_formu").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("form: ",$(this).serialize());
            $.ajax({
                url: "sayfalar/ogrenci_bilgileri.php",
                type: 'post',
                /*dataType: 'json',*/
                data: $(this).serialize()
            }).done(function(data) {
                $("tbody").html(data);
            }).fail(function(data) {
                console.log("error",data);
            });
        });
```

output:

```
eposta=
```

Comment: Why do u need button value?

Comment: because i use two button. a named seach button, a named excel-export button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like store button value into a variable and send with form serialize like this

JAVASCRIPT-

```
$("#ogrenci_arama_formu").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var btnValue = $(this).find('#ogrenci_ara').val();
  console.log("form: ", $(this).serialize()+'&ogrenci_ara='+btnValue);
  $.ajax({
    url: "sayfalar/ogrenci_bilgileri.php",
    type: 'post',
    /*dataType: 'json',*/
    data: $(this).serialize()+'&ogrenci_ara='+btnValue
  }).done(function(data) {
    $("tbody").html(data);
  }).fail(function(data) {
    console.log("error", data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Because only "successful controls" are serialized to the string, No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. You can read more about `serialize()` method from the link [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Comment: Thanks i understad